# Word for asking questions for the sake of it?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Sorry if I should have asked this in meta.

Comment: It's not about asking in meta, it's about properly forming a SWR. Please read the single-word-requests [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for help in that regard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Such questions would be **gratuitous**.

Compare: *ars gratia artis*

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to offer "**inquisitive**". It seemed appropriate.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inquisitive